# Array recebendo dois objetos

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array, objetos

Tenho dois objetos e queria criar um array desta maneira =>

```
[{"loj_codigo":2,"loj_fantasia":"teste 1"},{"loj_codigo":1,"loj_fantasia":"teste 2";}]}
```

Estou recebendo os seguintes objetos =>

```
Object {1: "1", 2: "2"}
Object {1: "teste 1", 2: "teste 2"}
```

Comment: Qual é a relação entre os objetos? Parece cruzado ou é sequencial? A chave 1 deve ser o quê no objeto novo?

Comment: @Sergio esse índice numérico  ali nos objetos está correto?

Comment: @durtto sim, pode usar-se numeros como chave/key em objetos. É limitado pois não se pode fazer `obj.3 = 'foo';`, nesse caso tem de ser `obj[3] = 'foo';``

Comment: O código 2 se refere à loja "teste 1" e o código 1 à "teste 2"? Pelos objetos que está recebendo fica complicado fazer esse vínculo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, isso deve resolver sua questão.

```
var obj1 = {1:"1", 2:"2"};
var obj2 = {1:"teste 1", 2:"teste 2"};
var arr  = [];

for( i in obj1 ){
    arr.push( JSON.parse('{"loj_codigo":'+i+',"loj_fantasia":"'+obj2[i]+'"}') );
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @Givanildo, consegui resolver a questão.